# Видоизменение дат в Django

Tags: django, дата

Нужно отобразить дату в Django вида: "Вчера, 9:10". Можно ли реализовать это посредством Django?

Comment: Кажется, нет. Проблема в слове "Вчера", такой формат `Django` не поддерживает ([список форматов](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date)). Вам нужно будет делать это на уровне представления, сравнивая текущую дату с необходимой, формируя строку и передавая её в контекст шаблона.

Comment: Ну или фильтр свой написать

Comment: Однозначно фильтр. через fiel.date() == datetime.now().date - timedelta(days=1) ,  fiel.date() == datetime.now().date + timedelta(days=1) и fiel.date() == datetime.now() подставляешь вчера, завтра, сегодня